# Accessing and displaying pivot table data

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-4, pivot-table

Theory:

Users can attend many events and many events can be attended by many users. Therefore, I have two many-to-many relationships within my models, linking to a pivot table (event_user). On attending each event, I want to be able to access the pivot table data (event_user) to see if they're already attending.

event_user:
    --id
    --event_id
    --user_id

For example, my seed data is:

user 1 attending both event 2 and 3. I want to be able to show this within a view.

The closest I have got is (logically):

```
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $attending = myApp\Event::find($id)->event;
    var_dump($attending); **But this var_dump returns NULL, but $id returns the correct ID.**

    $events = myApp\Event::all();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('events.index')->with('events', $events);
}
```

**My aim is to disable the 'attend' button, on any event where they are already attending, only leaving the attend-able events available!**

*Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you in advance.*

Any additional code which you may find necessary:

**Events Model:**

```
<?php

namespace myApp;
use Eloquent;

class Event extends Eloquent {

    public function consultant()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('myApp\Consultant');
    }

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('myApp\Location');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('myApp\User');
    }

}
```

**User Model:**

```
<?php

namespace myApp;
use Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Event');
    }

    public function practice()
    {
        return $this->belongToMany('Practice');
    }
```

**index.blade.php (showing the event list)**

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Events</strong></div>
  <!-- <div class="panel-body">
  </div> -->

  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Presenter</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($events as $event)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $event->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ date("j F Y", strtotime($event->date)) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->consultant()->first()->title }} {{ $event->consultant()->first()->surname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $event->location()->first()->address_1 }}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Attend</button></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way, that or I have misunderstood.

Firstly, you're trying to find an event with the same primary key as the currently authenticated user, which isn't correct, although it's an easy hole to fall down.

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$attending = myApp\Event::find($id)->event; 
// equivalent of: SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `id` = ?
```

Instead you'll want to do this

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$attending = myApp\Event::where('user_id', $id)->get(); 
// equivalent of: SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `user_id` = ? (user_id insted of events.id)
```

That being said, surely the user events can be accessed by just calling the event property on the auth user?

```
$user = Auth::user();
$attending = $user->event;
```

To take this one step further, and make it so that you can check inside the foreach loop, you could advanced the above code to look like the following

```
$user = Auth::user();
$attending = $user->event->lists('id');
```

This will make an array of ids from the returned events that you need to assign to the view

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('events.index', array('events' => $events, 'attending' => $attending));
```

Now you can freely access it in your foreach

```
@foreach($events as $event)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $event->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ date("j F Y", strtotime($event->date)) }}</td>
    <td>{{ $event->consultant()->first()->title }} {{ $event->consultant()->first()->surname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $event->location()->first()->address_1 }}</td>
    <td>
    @if (!in_array($event->id, $attending))
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Attend</button>
    @endif
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Also, seeing as Event is a reserved Alias (unless you've modified the config, which I wouldn't recommend), you'll want to specify the namespace in the relationship declaration within User

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('myApp\Event');
}
```

As a final point, it's not an issue as such, but in my own code I try to name relationships that have the potential to return multiple objects in the plural, so it would be `public function events();`.

Comment: what a great explanation, I can't thank you enough (it makes things clear for a beginner like me!)

The namespace was a slacking on my part, my bad.

Using the $attending = $user->event;, returns everything in JSON.. Including all data about the user, hashed password etc...

However, on the off chance, I was trying to solve this myself and this seemed to have brought up the two correct events that the user is attending: $attending = myApp\Event::has('user')->get();

But I am now struggling to match these within the foreach loop of my view to cross match whether they're attending!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped. The problem with `$attending = myApp\Event::has('user')->get();` is that it will return Events that have a corresponding user, even if the user isn't the current one. If you're echoing out the contents of $attending, then Laravel will automatically make it a JSON string, instead use `dd($attending);`.

Comment: I modified my answer to include a way to check it

Comment: That all makes sense! Although, it now returns this error on my view: ErrorException - Undefined variable: attending. Has the $attending variable not been passed through? And thank you again, you've been more than helpful.

Comment: Ahh yes, you'll need to pass it through manually, see my answer. I'm glad I could be of help, all I ask for is rep :P aha

Comment: You'll kill me soon enough, the error now appears as "ErrorException
Undefined variable: events" within the foreach loop in the view! I have no qualms in giving you rep, I wish I could up-vote more than once.

Comment: Ahaha totally my bad, it should be `'events' => $events` not `'events', $events` ahaha well I see most rep is given from being chose as the right answer I think (I've only been using this site for 3 days)

Comment: You, Sir, are a God send, you should be charging for this sort of advice! It works a treat, thank you and thanks again.

Comment: No problem what so ever, glad to help.

Comment: A quick question, if possible Ollieread, could you explain to me what's happening in this line of code please: $attending = $user->event->lists('id'); I can't find the 'list' function on Laravel documentation.

Comment: It's unfortunate not documented, to solve your issue I went through the source code of Illuminate\Support\Collection. What it actually does, is it makes an array (a list) of the specified attributes from the collection. So in this instance, it grabs the id attribute from every object in the collection, and makes a nice array for us to use. The actual method can be seen here: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#334-365